# Keeping the month fix And Year varied in reporting service

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012 and I have searched on internet about the problem I am experiencing a small problem , 
In the header I want the following Date format.

So from Current Month + 5 years till the Fiscal Year.

e.g. If I run this month it should display 
Dec 2015 (Current Month) through June(Fiscal Year ending, always will be ending in June ) 2020 (Five Years from the Current year) . 
What should be expression in Textbox For SSRS 
P.S - I am rendering Report into PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work the way you want with any date:

```
=FORMAT(TODAY, "MMM yyyy") & " through " & FORMAT(TODAY.AddYears(5).AddMonths(6 - MONTH(TODAY())), "MMM yyyy")
```

You can replace TODAY with a field if you need to.

Comment: it is Working , but Will it work for every month ? like when I run on Jan 2016 it will show Jan 2016 through June 2016  ?

Comment: Yes - **TODAY** is the SSRS variable for the **current date** and the FORMAT function extracts the **month** and **year** from it. The second date adds five years subtracts the number of the month and **adds 6** from **TODAY** so it will always be **JUN**.

Comment: Thanks @hannover Fist , It Solved my Problem :)